# The response body is a byte stream. See the service documentation for allowed content types

Tags: c#, json, serialization, rest, memorystream

When I used REST to call my WCF service it skips the method being called with the following error:

> The response body is a byte stream.
>   See the service documentation for
>   allowed content types.

I am dealing with placing objects in memory and then trying to serialize them as a JSON string. To do this, I have an interface to my service contract:

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IDashboardService
    {

        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "dashboard/group/id/{id}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        Stream GetGroupById(string id);


    }
```

And in my service contract overrides the method that is being skipped:

```
public class Dashboard : GroupBase, Contracts.IDashboardService
{
        public Dashboard() : base()
        {

            if (!ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
                throw new WebException("Unauthorized: Class: Dashboard, Method: Dashboard()",
                    System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

        }

        public override System.IO.Stream GetGroupById(string id)
        {
            return base.GetGroupById(id);
        }

}
```

Here is the base method:

```
 public virtual Stream GetGroupById(string id)
        {
            byte[] bytes = null;

            var groupId = System.Convert.ToInt32(id);
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            switch (groupId)
            {
                case 0: // regions
                    var regions = GroupRepository.GetAllRegions();
                        bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializer.Serialize(regions));
                    break;
                case 1: // customers
                    var customers = CustomerRepository.GetAllCustomers();
                        bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializer.Serialize(customers));
                    break;
            }

            return new MemoryStream(bytes);

        }
```

Any idea how I can get this working? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a stream and then tell WCF to format it as JSON.  Just remove the MessageFormat attribute and set the Content Type header manually to application/Json

Comment: hi, thanks. i don't think this was the problem - i was getting this error even before I put the ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json in my WebGet attribute.

Comment: Yes, I just tested it and am still getting the same error... any other thoughts?

Comment: Hi Darrel, I think I am getting closer to the answer and I have summed up the problem (a little better) in another post. If you have a chance, please give it a read (I appreciate your help). Thanks again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898663/system-io-stream-to-data-transfer-object-prior-to-wcf-rest-serialization

Comment: @Code Sherpa What stack are you using to call the service?

Answer (score 1):

I had to put this line in before returning the memory stream to get it to format as JSON:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
```